# TypeError: $(...).lightGallery(...).destroy is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightgallery, lightgallery-1

I am getting this error from firefox:

```
TypeError: $(...).lightGallery(...).destroy is not a function
```

I am using following plugin for play video and show image gallery 
https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery.

I want re-initialize lightGallery because I am using ajax to add element dynamically in container. It was working fine with previous version of lightGallery but it is not working with current version.

I am using following code.

```
// destroy previous gallery
$("#lightGallery2").lightGallery({
  selector : '.image_gallery',
  videojs: true,
  download: false
}).destroy();

// re-initialize
$("#lightGallery2").lightGallery({
  selector: '.image_gallery',
  videojs: true,
  download: false
});
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Log a bug if you think it is one: https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
$lg.on('onBeforeClose.lg',function(event, index, fromTouch, fromThumb){
    try{$lg.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);}catch(ex){};
});
```

Comment: 2 aspects from this were important for me, you must access the object via the data property bag `$("#lightGallery2").data('lightGallery')` and I had to pass true as a parameter to destroy => `$("#lightGallery2").data('lightGallery').destroy(true);`

Answer (score 1):

For destroy **data** you should add data attribute to your gallery then destroy it, for example if you apply gallery to all links:

```
var myGallery = 'body',
    lightgallery = function() {
         $( myGallery ).attr('data-lightGallery', '1');
         $( myGallery ).lightGallery({selector: 'a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".jpeg"], a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".gif"]'});
    };
```

Then:

```
$( myGallery ).data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
lightgallery();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is written like most plugins/widgets, you should be calling the destroy method like this.

```
$("#lightGallery2").lightGallery("destroy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following method to destroy lightgallery version 1.2.x.

```
var $lg = $('#lightGallery2');

$lg.lightGallery({
  selector : '.image_gallery',
  videojs: true,
  download: false
});

$lg.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
```

Here is the [docs](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html#methods)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. but it still not working it showing following error.  TypeError: $lg.data(...) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I simply created a global variable. It allows me to perform the desired function.

```
var PLUGIN; // global variable
...
if(PLUGIN) PLUGIN.data('lightGallery').destroy(true); // destroy 
PLUGIN = $("#lightGallery2").lightGallery();
```